# st: 1 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0 from file created with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have created a new mp4 file by using concat on my mp4s with this:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,tcp,http,pipe -f concat -i - -c copy ${videoName%/}.mp4
```

I then, want to reduce the file size of the newly created file with:

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -s 1280x720 -c:a copy "$videoName"
```

But I am presented with

```
hutber@hutber:/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore Hill/1920/Week_14_6-2_W/Clips$ sd
Gtk-Message: 12:18:37.761: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore Hill/1920/Week_14_6-2_W/Clips/vlc-record-2020-01-25-20h28m06s-S3510003.MP4-.mp4
/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore Hill/1920/Week_14_6-2_W/Clips/01.26.2020/vlc-record-2020-01-25-20h28m06s-S3510003.MP4-_01.26.2020_12.18_SD.mp4
ffmpeg version N-49161-g50e194e6e1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x6844880] st: 1 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x6844880] st: 1 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore Hill/1920/Week_14_6-2_W/Clips/vlc-record-2020-01-25-20h28m06s-S3510003.MP4-.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41avc1
    creation_time   : 2020-01-25T20:28:19.000000Z
    playback_requirements: QuickTime 6.0 or greater
    playback_requirements-eng: QuickTime 6.0 or greater
    encoder         : vlc 3.0.8 stream output
    encoder-eng     : vlc 3.0.8 stream output
  Duration: 00:00:12.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 61318 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-25T20:28:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 61056 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-25T20:28:19.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore Hill/1920/Week_14_6-2_W/Clips/01.26.2020/vlc-record-2020-01-25-20h28m06s-S3510003.MP4-_01.26.2020_12.18_SD.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Just in case this is helpful at all here is my sh script (i've a JS dev :p)

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(zenity --file-selection)
currentDateTime=$(date +'%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M')
currentDate=$(date +'%m.%d.%Y')
safeVideoName="${file/ /_}"
safeVideoName="${file/.mp4/}"
safeVideoName="${file/.mp4/}"
filename=${safeVideoName##*/}

fullpath="${safeVideoName%/*}/$currentDate"
videoName="${fullpath}/${filename}_${currentDateTime}_SD.mp4"
echo $file
echo $videoName
mkdir -p $fullpath
ffmpeg -i "$file" -s 1280x720 -c:a copy "$videoName"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, the parameter substitution for `mkdir` was not quoted:

```bsh
mkdir -p $fullpath
```

should be

```bsh
mkdir -p "$fullpath"
```

---

The "Missing key frame" message [shouldn't be a problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1480252/convert-a-file-with-missing-key-frame).

As you can see from ffmpeg's last line:

```
...: No such file or directory
```

This was the problem – because bash splits unquoted parameter substitutions, the `mkdir` command in your script tried to make two directories, not the one which you intended. The result being that you were telling `ffmpeg` to output a file in a directory which didn't exist.

As there was a single space – there should now be two directories:

1. `/mnt/googledrive/Winchmore`
2. and in whichever directory the script was executed from – a new directory named `Hill`

You may wish to remove those.